# why can not Register android device to Windows Azure Notification hub

Tags: android, azure, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I'm following this article; http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-android-get-started.

when i use Nexus 4 it works fine, but it doesn't work on
Samsung Note 2 ,Samsung S3 mini (actually all samsung device) and Nexus 7 (2013).

Nexus 4 and Nexus 7 (2013) have the same Android version. 
Although i've tried to change compileSdkVersion and minSdkVersion but it still can not register. It return this message : "com.microsoft.windowsazure.messaging.NotificationHubUnauthorizedException: Unauthorized"

--AndoridManifest.Xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<permission android:name="com.myapp.pckg.abc.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.myapp.pckg.abc.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>

<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <receiver android:name="com.microsoft.windowsazure.notifications.NotificationsBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="myapp.pckg.abc" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

/* build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "myapp.pckg.abc"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'

compile 'com.google.guava:guava:17.0'

compile files('libs/notifications-1.0.1.jar')

compile files('libs/mobileservices-2.0.2.jar')

compile files('libs/mobileservices-2.0.2-javadoc.jar')

compile files('libs/mobileservices-2.0.2-sources.jar')

compile files('libs/notification-hubs-0.4.jar')

compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:6.5.87'
```

}
 */

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen that article too, it is not up to date. Maybe the gcm structure is changed by Google.